# php validation code format

Tags: php, html

Okay I have this MySQL database form and am trying to add validation to it. After 2 days of fighting with it, I thought I would get some advice. Would like that the selected item from dropdown and Firstname, Phone, Email,  are all required. Then I want to verify that the data in the Firstname, Lastname, Phone (doesn't have to be any special format), Email and Comments are all acceptable formats before putting in database. Here is what I have so far:

```
 <?php 
include('inc_header.php');
if(isset($_POST['add']))
 {
 require('dbcon.php');
 if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
$Id = addslashes ($_POST['Id']);
$List = addslashes ($_POST['List']);
$Firstname = addslashes ($_POST['Firstname']);
$Lastname = addslashes ($_POST['Lastname']);
$Phone = addslashes ($_POST['Phone']);
$Email= addslashes ($_POST['Email']);
$Calltime = addslashes ($_POST['Calltime']);
$Comment = addslashes ($_POST['Comment']);

}
else
{
$Id = $_POST['Id'];
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
$List = $_POST['List'];
$Firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
$Lastname = $_POST['Lastname'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Calltime = $_POST['Calltime'];
$Comment = $_POST['Comment'];
 }

 $error = '';

 //put chosen function here
  function validate_Firstname($input, $pattern = "/([A-Za-z0-9])")
 {
    return !preg_match($pattern, $input);
   }

  function validate_Phone($input, $pattern = "/([A-Za-z0-9])")
 {
    return !preg_match($pattern, $input);
  }
 function isValidEmail( $Email ){
    return filter_var( $Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
 }

  //get values and validate each one as required
  $List = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['List']);
     if(!$List){ $error .= "Please choose one<br />"; }

  $Firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Firstname']);
    if(!$Firstname){ $error .= "First name is required<br />"; }

//get values and validate each one as required
  $Lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Lastname']);
    if(!$Lastname){ $error .= "Last name is required<br />"; }

  //repeat for each field
  $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
    if(!isValidEmail($Email)){ $error .= "The email entered is invalid<br />"; }

  //and so on...

  if(!$error){
     //add insert into database code here

 $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts ".
   "(`Id`,`Date`,`List`,`Firstname`,`Lastname`,`Phone`,`Email`,`Calltime`,`Comment`)".
 "VALUES'$Id,','$Date','$List','$Firstname','$Lastname','$Phone','$Email','$Calltime','$Comment')     ";
 mysql_select_db('hmintcwa_contacts');
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
 if(! $retval )
 {
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 echo "Entered data successfully<br /><br /><a href=contactsadd.php><font       color=#000000>Back</font></a>\n";
 mysql_close($conn);
}
else
 {

 ?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="ContactForm">
 <table bgcolor="#000000" width="500" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0">
 <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id">
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Requested Info</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><select name="List">
 <option value="0" > Please Choose One </option>
 <option value="Market Analysis" > Market Analysis </option>
 <option value="Consultation" > Consultation </option></select></td></tr>
  <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Date</td>
 <input name="Date" type="hidden" id="Date" value="<? print(Date("l F d, Y")); ?>" />
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><? print(Date("l F d, Y")); ?></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Firstname</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input name="Firstname" type="text" size="20" id="Firstname"></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Lastname</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Lastname"  size="20" id="Lastname"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Phone</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Phone" size="20" id="Phone"></td></tr>
 <tr>
<td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Email</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Email"  size="20" id="Email"></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Preferred Calltime</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Calltime"  size="20" id="Calltime">  &nbsp;&nbsp; If none put N/A</td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Comment</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><textarea name="Comment" cols="40" rows="8" id="Comment"></textarea></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"><br>
 <input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Contact"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Clear Form"><input type=button value="Cancel" onClick="history.go(-1)"><br>&nbsp;
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 <br>&nbsp;</center>
 <?php
 }
  ?>
   </body>
       </html>
```

So far I just keep chasing error message. Please forgive formatting I am trying to learn be gentle.

Comment: What error message? If you want help, please share anything applicable to your problem.

Comment: sorry I was trying to see why it didn't put the whole code in here. first of all the form works great to post to database, after adding the functions part I now have an error unexpected $end on line ...

Comment: If that's your entire block then you're missing a closing brace (as well as a `</table>` and `</form>`)

Comment: It didn't post all of the code

Comment: How about an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19871167/edit) then?

Comment: okay so I tried to edit and still it is only putting half the code in. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Got it to show whole code finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an end bracket for this statement:  (`if(!$error){`)

**edit**: the `}` you were missing is actually a closing bracket for `if(isset($_POST['add']))`, not magic quotes.  sorry!

```
     //and so on...

    if(!$error)
    {
      //add insert into database code here

       // this probably won't run right... 
       // you're missing a ( after the word values...
       // insert into tablename (id, name, stuff) values (1,'gloomy','stuff); 

       // this part of your statement is not correct:  "VALUES'$Id,','$Date',
       // and the commas are off, too.

       $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts ".
               "(`Id`,`Date`,`List`,`Firstname`,`Lastname`,`Phone`,`Email`,`Calltime`,`Comment`)".
               "VALUES'$Id,','$Date','$List','$Firstname','$Lastname','$Phone','$Email','$Calltime','$Comment')     ";

       // print your SQL here to make sure it is correct.  
       // copy and paste it to run it directly in the DB. if it won't run there
       // it won't run here
       print $sql."<br/>"; 

       mysql_select_db('hmintcwa_contacts');
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

       if(! $retval )  {
          die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       echo "Entered data successfully<br /><br /><a href=contactsadd.php><font       color=#000000>Back</font></a>\n";
       mysql_close($conn);

    } // <-------- you're missing this closing bracket

} // this ends the statement for  if(isset($_POST['add']))  { .... 
else
{
    // REMOVE this... or else it will print the world else somewhere
    // i put this here to debug...
    print "else<br/>";

?>
```

formatting your code helps a lot

**EDIT**: looking over the code, there's a lot of small issues everywhere.  I'm not trying to be mean.  I'm just saying... why don't you try to break the code up into smaller pieces and make sure all the parts will compile and work properly on their own before putting them all together?  This is a lot to tackle all at once.  Just try to dump your variables (arrays in particular) when you need to and each time you write a new chunk, make sure it works correctly and make sure everything else still works correctly.  Then, move forward... it's easier to isolate problems that way.

---

**this works for me.  it uses pdo.**  oh, and now you don't need to worry about sql injection as much.  this pretty much takes care of it completely.  like everything, there's always ways around things but you do not need to check for magic quotes, you do not need to escape anything.  doing the parameterization handles all that for you.

**edit**:  so... when you write code... don't write a whole bunch of stuff and *then* see if it all works.  write a few lines.  test.  write some more.  test.  make sure the new stuff works.  make sure the old stuff still works.  write a little more.  i have absolutely no clue how you got that far with so many little issues.  i'm not trying to be mean.  write code in lil chunks, though.  even logic.  always test everything again, then move on.

**and** I left my debug statements in there... the `print_r($array)` and the `var_dump(variable)` so that you can see how that stuff is set up, where your values are coming from, what everything holds at whatever point, how to use them, where to put them.  it will print weird things now.  comment it out or remove them.

I understand there's a lot more tutorials for `mysql_` functions but they are old and not safe at all.  If you have issues using PDO, just come back to StackOverflow with your errors, issues and *code* and just write a disclaimer that "you know mysql_ functions are bad but the pdo is harder to learn" and people will be happy to help because it is that much better.

these are important PDO pages:

- [$stmt->bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
- [$stmt->execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
- [$stmt->rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) (I didn't use this but you might want it later)
- [$stmt->fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) - for your `select` statements.  this returns all the data in a huge array
- [how to prepare statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

and the code...

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

// include('inc_header.php');


function validate_Firstname($input, $pattern = "/([A-Za-z0-9])") {
   return !preg_match($pattern, $input);
}

function validate_Phone($input, $pattern = "/([A-Za-z0-9])") {
   return !preg_match($pattern, $input);
}

function isValidEmail($Email) {
   return filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

// ====================================================================================
// ====================================================================================

if (!empty($_POST)) {
   print "<pre>This is your \$_POST array \n\n".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>"; 
}

$error = '';

if (isset($_POST['add'])) 
{
   // require('dbcon.php');
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

   // what if the array index ['whatever'] doesn't exist?  errors.  
   // so we need to check and make sure it is set... then assign.  
   // this also gives us a blank default value, which is nice.... 
   $id        = isset($_POST['Id'])        ? $_POST['Id']        : 'NULL'; 
   $date      = isset($_POST['Date'])      ? $_POST['Date']      : '';  
   $list      = isset($_POST['List'])      ? $_POST['List']      : '';  
   $firstname = isset($_POST['Firstname']) ? $_POST['Firstname'] : ''; 
   $lastname  = isset($_POST['Lastname'])  ? $_POST['Lastname']  : ''; 
   $phone     = isset($_POST['Phone'])     ? $_POST['Phone']     : ''; 
   $email     = isset($_POST['Email'])     ? $_POST['Email']     : '';  
   $calltime  = isset($_POST['Calltime'])  ? $_POST['Calltime']  : '';  
   $comment   = isset($_POST['Comment'])   ? $_POST['Comment']   : '';   

   if (!$list) {
      $error .= "Please choose one<br />";
   } 
   if (!$firstname) {
      $error .= "First name is required<br />";
   } 
   if (!$lastname) {
      $error .= "Last name is required<br />";
   } 
   if (!isValidEmail($email)) {
      $error .= "The email entered is invalid<br />";
   }

   var_dump($error); 

   if (!$error) 
   {     
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts (id, date, list, firstname, lastname, phone, email, calltime, comment) \n". 
                              " VALUES (:id, :date, :list, :firstname, :lastname, :phone, :email, :calltime, :comment) "); 

      $success = $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':date'=>$date, ':list'=>$list, ':firstname'=>$firstname, 'lastname'=>$lastname,  
                                      ':phone'=>$phone, ':email'=>$email, ':calltime'=>$calltime, ':comment'=>$comment)); 

      if (!$success) 
      { 
          echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n"; 
          print "<pre>".print_r($dbh->errorInfo(),true)."/<pre>"; 
      }  
      else 
      {
         print "it worked!  the new row's ID is ".$conn->lastInsertId()."...!!!<br/>";
      }

      echo "Entered data successfully<br/><br/>";


   } // end of  if (!$error) { ... }  
   else 
   {  
      print "$error<br/>";
   }

   echo "<a href='contactsadd.php' style='font-color=#000000'>Back</a>\n";

} // end of if(isset($_POST['add']))  { ... }
else
{ 

// ====================================================================================
// ====================================================================================
?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="ContactForm">
 <table bgcolor="#000000" width="500" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0">
 <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id">
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Requested Info</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><select name="List">
 <option value="0" > Please Choose One </option>
 <option value="Market Analysis" > Market Analysis </option>
 <option value="Consultation" > Consultation </option></select></td></tr>
  <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Date</td>
 <input name="Date" type="hidden" id="Date" value="<?php print(Date("l F d, Y")); ?>" />
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><?phpprint(Date("l F d, Y")); ?></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Firstname</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input name="Firstname" type="text" size="20" id="Firstname"></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Lastname</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Lastname"  size="20" id="Lastname"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Phone</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Phone" size="20" id="Phone"></td></tr>
 <tr>
<td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Email</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Email"  size="20" id="Email"></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Preferred Calltime</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><input type="text" name="Calltime"  size="20" id="Calltime">  &nbsp;&nbsp; If none put N/A</td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">Comment</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left"><textarea name="Comment" cols="40" rows="8" id="Comment"></textarea></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#e9e9e9" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center"><br>
 <input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Contact"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Clear Form"><input type=button value="Cancel" onClick="history.go(-1)"><br>&nbsp;
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 <br>&nbsp;</center>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: cool the form came back but now it has else printed at the top, no error messages when fields are empty, and doesn't add info to the database

Comment: @user2970887:  use this: http://beta.phpformatter.com/  I tested your code in there and it does a really good job with it.  If you keep everything indented and aligned, you can find missing brackets easily.

Comment: @user2970887:  Yeah, to remove the "else", just remove where I put `print "else<br/>;" for debugging.  I had to remove your HTML but needed a statement to hold its place.

Comment: About adding things to the DB -> did you make the changes that the other answer suggested?  In my comments, I made a note that your `insert` statement wasn't correct, too.  The entire code has small issues everywhere that need to be debugged out.

Comment: Thank you I fixed the issues and took out new code to see if The form works. It's fine without the validation stuff but once I put it in then nothing happens no errors no submit to database just a blank page

Comment: before `if(!$error)`, dump `$error` to the screen.  (`print $error;`)

Comment: and before this line `$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );`, put `print $sql;` It's going through your code.  The blank page is a side effect from your validation but you never print an error.  As is, that query will never successfully run, either.  **You need to learn to debug**, all I'm doing is going through your code and dumping variables.  I don't have a connection to your DB or the included files but I am still able to find the cause of all these different issues.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not a programmer so I am learning as I go. I did as you said and fixed everything. The query works fine as long as the validation crap isn't there. I put print $sql; and saw nothing

Comment: No, you're good.  I'm just saying.  It's a skill in itself. Ummm... I saw the sql statement.  Do you have error reporting on?  It was after an error for a variable named "date" being undefined... add this to the top of your page:  `ini_set('display_errors',1);ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);error_reporting(-1);`... yeah, the error is b/c initialized `$Date` for the query.

Comment: I fixed it as in where I had a comma in the wrong place and no ( before values. I would print an error if I knew where to tell it to print and if it even threw an error. frustrating

Comment: the commas are wrong, too.  and `$Date` has no value.  do you see the `$sql` being printed yet?  (that's an important thing, you can't debug if you cant see errors)...  this is what it prints for me (there are syntax errors):  `INSERT INTO contacts (`Id`,`Date`,`List`,`Firstname`,`Lastname`,`Phone`,`Email`,`Calltime`,`Comment`)VALUES',','','Market Analysis','sdf','sdf','sdf','gloomy.penguin@gmail.com','9','sdfsd')     `

Comment: nothing prints out. I fixed all of the commas and stuff I have the Date as a hidden input and it is echoed as the value

Comment: do the errors print out, though?  PHP errors... did you add this?  `ini_set('display_errors',1);ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);error_reporting‌​(-1);` (there's a spider in my rum n coke..?!?!!)  okay, you gotta debug on your own a little here... dump variables everywhere.  turn on error reporting.  comment out code.  comment out inside of  that whole `if (!$error)` part and just put a print statement in there.  see if that will load for you.  slowly add stuff back in.  you gotta get that error reporting on otherwise you can't debug.

Comment: So I got errors printing out finally. The functions for empty fields and valid email are working, but not for valid names or phone numbers. also I get this for inserting into database string(0) "" INSERT INTO contacts (`Id`,`Date`,`List`,`Firstname`,`Lastname`,`Phone`,`Email`,`Calltime`,`Comment`)VALUES('','Friday November 08, 2013','Market Analysis','me','me','555555555','me@me.com','7','hello') 

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home/..../public_html/.......php on line 107

Comment: I don't think the `ID` is right and it's causing the query to fail.  I don't know why you're getting that error.  This is the line, right...?  `$retval = mysql_query($sql,$conn);` and `$sql` is a string, right?  So... `var_dump($sql)` and make sure.  Can you test your query straight in the DB and see if it runs correctly?  (seriously... just troubleshoot... debug... you can do it... the errors are informative)  do a `print mysql_error()` after your `mysql_query` to see if that insert works.

Comment: oh, and give me a green check mark for my post here.  (i think i deserve it, lol...) and an upvote if you can.  (you don't have to, i just want you to)... if `ID` is an `auto_increment` column, change it to `values (null, ...` if ID is empty.  I guess use `$_POST['ID']` if it has a value... which I'm not sure why it ever would if you're inserting new values.  Does that form even have an ID field?  where is this ID coming from even?  I think you can use `null` and be safe with that.

Comment: hey - post your `create table` statement for `contacts` in your post up there... I am gonna re-write your code.  I'm bored.  The spider is still in the cup.  (just do a `show create table contacts` in your mysql)

Comment: Can't find how to do it in phpmyadmin    the table has

Comment: Can't find how to do it in phpmyadmin    the table has Id (auto), Date (text), List (text) is a dropdown on the form, Firstname (text), Lastname (text), Phone (text), Email(text), Calltime (text), Comment (text) pretty basic

Comment: it's okay.  I made the ID field `int unsigned auto_increment primary key` and everything else is a `varchar(100)`.  new code that uses `PDO` is up there.  i had to comment out your included files.

Comment: I did add code to tell me if I was connected to the database and it says that I am, but I can't get it to add anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your query arguments are backwards, and you should be using mysqli_. Here is the correct order.

```
$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

[mysqli_query documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: We should probably suggest OP not even bother learning `mysql_` functions because they will be going away fairly soon... use `pdo` or `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: You beat me to the edit! I was so distracted by the poorly formatted code that I actually overlooked that part.

Comment: I saw that.  Good job looking out for OP.

Comment: Thank you. I have been doing a lot of reading Arrgh. Did the code actually work on putting info into the database. I have fixed all of the errors that I found and formatting. But it does not add anything to the database and does not give any errors about not being connected. I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: i am learning and I know that I am connected to the database because I put in the code to tell me so.